# Nietzche quoting Descartes... without source

Tags: epistemology, history-of-philosophy, nietzsche, descartes

In the [Will to Power](https://books.google.it/books?id=4K_qDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT361&lpg=PT361&dq=%22omne%20illud%20verum%20est,%20quod%20clare%20et%20distincte%20percipitur%22%20Descartes&source=bl&ots=WlceiY1DHr&sig=0-MwCzx4cjSpvp7ziXGuIECEVaY&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp2YaQ8svbAhVIOBQKHThNCe8Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22omne%20illud%20verum%20est%2C%20quod%20clare%20et%20distincte%20percipitur%22%20Descartes&f=false) Nietzche quotes Descartes

> *omne illud verum est, quod clare et distincte percipitur*

However I cannot find the quoted source. Can anyone identify it?

Comment: I can't find 'percipitur' in the Meditations or the Principles but I haven't checked the Replies to Objections. It looks as if Nietzsche was either misquoting from memory or giving his own gloss, without textual exactitude, on Descartes' tenet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Descartes' [Meditations (1641), III.2](http://www.wright.edu/~charles.taylor/descartes/meditation3l.html) :

> illud omne esse verum, quòd valde clare & distincte percipio.

[John Veitch English translation of 1901](http://www.wright.edu/~charles.taylor/descartes/meditation3.html) :

> all that is very clearly and distinctly apprehended (conceived) is true.

---

See also [Principia Philosophiae (1644), Pars prima, XXX](https://books.google.it/books?id=lHpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA11) :

> omnia qua clare percepimus, vera esse.

Comment: Accepted answer. Still Veitch translation from Latin is a bit loose. *Percipio* means "I  perceive": the personal perspective is very important in Descartes reasoning...

Comment: @GiacomoTesio - Agreed. But also the French transl of 1647 (presumably known to D) sound "impersonal" : "toutes les choses que nous concevons fort clairement et fort distinctement, sont toutes vraies."

Answer (score 3):

In Descartes's *Meditations*, I found

> illud omne esse verum, quòd valde clare & distincte percipio.

MEDITATIO III; De Deo, quòd existat; par. 2. http://www.wright.edu/~charles.taylor/descartes/meditation3l.html

Another source puts the quote in Meditations III, par. 1. http://www.unicaen.fr/puc/sources/prodescartes/consult/descartes/Oeuvres/Oeuvres_Descartes/meditationes.xml/meditationes_objection_5_3

That is the closest example I could find. Perhaps Descartes wrote a similar quote elsewhere.